# If gen matrix has even weigth rows, do codewords have even weigth for non binary code?

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory, binary

Is that true that in a non binary code C every codeword has even weight if and only if every row of G has even weight?

Answer (score 1):

No. Look at the $2 \times 2$ matrices $G$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3$. (There are only $3^4$ of them, so you can enumerate them to find a counterexample.)